# How do I insert the contents of a variable after or between a specified line number from a bash script?

Tags: bash, sed, macos

My script modifies a configuration file by inserting some settings as a block of text stored in a variable after the 4th line. I understand there are some incompatibilities in MacOS's version of sed so I installed the GNU version, but I don't know which SED is running.

> #!/bin/bash
>
> SCRIPT_LINES="for all "vars";\find Runtime ("stm32") use
> "c++";\n\n"  sed -i'' "4i$SCRIPT_LINES" environment.cfg

The SED's syntax is nonsensical and I would love an alternative, but there doesn't seem to be a good one.  How do I insert a block of text contained in a variable into another file from a bash script?

Comment: Show the contents of the variable and sed command clearly delineated. Right now they are a humbled mess where it's hard to tell what is variable

Comment: This OP is a time waster. Just doesn't respond to queries .

Comment: And abusive too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find sed's syntax nonsensical, you can insert a line at a certain place in lots of different ways. One way that's pretty easy to understand:

```
( head -n 4 environment.cfg && echo "$script_lines" && tail -n +5 environment.cfg ) > /tmp/tmp-environment.cfg
mv /tmp/tmp-environment.cfg environment.cfg
```

I.e., echo the first four lines of a file, then echo the variable, then print everything from line 5 on. Store the result in a temporary file, then copy it over.

That way you can avoid `sed`. ☺

But I think with GNU sed, it's just

```
sed -i "4a $script_lines" environment.cfg
```

With OS X sed:

```
sed -i '' "4a $script_lines" environment.cfg
```

To tell what version you're running:

```
sed --version
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the error "sed: 1: "environment.cfg": unterminated substitute in regular expression". This might be the GNU vs NONGNU issue.

Comment: You have no substitute s/// command so how come this message ?

Comment: I think it's interpreting the variable as regular expression.

Comment: sed --version
sed: illegal option -- -
usage: sed script [-Ealnru] [-i extension] [file ...]
 sed [-Ealnu] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: Are you properly escaping the backslash, etc. in the variable?: `script_lines='for all "vars";\\find Runtime ("stm32") use "c++";\n\n'` : note the single quotes so you can use double quotes inside, and the `\\` before the find. Or you can use my first suggestion.

Comment: If it doesn't allow `--version`, it's not GNU sed. Try `which -a sed` to find all seds installed and which come first in the `$PATH`

Comment: only a /usr/bin/sed

Comment: Doesn't seem like you succeeded in installing GNU sed. (Or it might have gotten installed as `gsed`.)

Comment: I think I installed it through brew. I think it keeps its own install locations. Anyway, the head and tail got rid of my ail. UNIX should be buried deep in the Yucca mountains with all the other radioactive waste.

Comment: As I mentioned in my last comment, I think homebrew installs GNU sed as `gsed` by default but you can make it install as `sed` if you give it a certain flag. (Google it.) It's not UNIX that should be buried, it's OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `perl` instead (the non-standard `-i` extensions that some `sed` implementations have added in some incompatible ways were inspired by `perl`'s):

```
#! /bin/sh -
SCRIPT_LINES='for all "vars";find Runtime ("stm32") use "c++"

' perl -i -pe '$_ = "$ENV{SCRIPT_LINES}$_" if $. == 4' environment.cfg
```

Comment: Perl is so yucky and icky!  I rather swim with hungry crocodiles than write a line of Perl.